# How do I avoid mobclix autoplaying fullscreen ads?

Tags: android, ios, fullscreen, mobclix, interstitial

We're developing an app using mobclix to provide advertisements.  Our android version works as desired, but our iOS version occasionally gets fullscreen (I believe they call them interstitial) ads showing up without clicking on the ad banner.  This is extremely irritating as it happens even when you're interacting with the app.  [ **Edit:** we've now seen the issue on android as well, so it's not iOS specific. ]

We've made sure that we're returning `NO` from `adViewCanAutoplay` (and returning `YES` from `richMediaRequiresUserInteraction`, although that doesn't seem related).  We also have `Allow Auto-play Ads` in our dashboard set to `No` for all ad units and the `Platform:iPhone` / `Ad Unit:Fullscreen` has `Ads Running` set to `No`

We've submitted a support request from mobclix, but they've just said we need to send them screenshots of the ads so they can pull them.  It seems weird that their functionality can't detect an ad trying to resize the ad banner to fullscreen and prevent it, and doubly weird that they're expecting us to curate their content for them.  Note: this is after waiting a week to see if changing settings in the dashboard, etc takes a while to go into effect.

Does anyone know of a way to make mobclix behave?

Comment: are you still having this problem, or did you manage to get it resolved?

Comment: Mobclix told us that an ad provider was serving the wrong sized ads and we should disable them as an provider, and now the problem seems to be gone.  I wouldn't call this "resolved" as this doesn't fix the problem of mobclix functionality not explicitly disallowing oversized ads.  Currently looking into other ad middleware, and if we ever get oversized ads again without asking for them, that'll force our hand

Comment: Never got a solution to this other than to block Mobile Theory as an ad provider.  They apparently serve full screen ads when you're only asking for banner ads.  Still not sure why mobclix's functionality can't detect that their banner is attempting to resize and just block the thing, so I'm not posting this as an answer.  Also this is not just an iOS issue, we saw one on our android version the other day.